# HTML / CSS Transparent Image Keeps showing background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert a logo into the header of my webpage, and although it is transparent when I save it locally, it still shows a grid when the URL is inserted into my stylesheet. How can I get rid of that ugly grid in the logo?

```
header {
      background-color: #5C9632;
      background-image: url(https://library.kissclipart.com/20190218/sgq/kissclipart-cartoon-snake-logo-clipart-snakes-logo-9150a5362e4635c4.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check again, your image has a grid indeed, the background is not entirely transparent.

Comment: Your image has a grid in background that's why You see it :) ... save it as JPG then You will see that it have grid in background

Answer (score 0):

**DO:**
You just need to download the image from https://www.kissclipart.com/ using the `Free Download` button.

**DON'T**
Using right-click, then Save Image, it will get you the grid photo.

Your CSS code is fine.

Comment: Hi, how do I reference the saved image within my CSS file? I can only reference the URL at the moment and I think that's where I'm failing lol

Comment: Hi, you can save the image in the same folder as your .html file. And then just add background-image: url(image_name.png). That's it, it doesn't have to be the absolute url with https and such.

Answer (score 0):

Here is image without background ;)

[image]

Comment: click "save image as" ;)

Comment: Hi, how do I reference the saved image within my CSS file? I can only reference the URL at the moment.

Comment: if you do not know how to save image ... start learning basics